# Object index key type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I defined my generic type as

```
interface IDictionary<TValue> {
    [key: string|number]: TValue;
}
```

But TSLint's complaining. How am I supposed to define an object index type that can have either as key? I tried these as well but no luck.

```
interface IDictionary<TKey, TValue> {
    [key: TKey]: TValue;
}

interface IDictionary<TKey extends string|number, TValue> {
    [key: TKey]: TValue;
}

type IndexKey = string | number;

interface IDictionary<TValue> {
    [key: IndexKey]: TValue;
}

interface IDictionary<TKey extends IndexKey, TValue> {
    [key: TKey]: TValue;
}
```

**None of the above work.**

### So how then?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can achieve that just by using a
`IDictionary<TValue> { [key: string]: TValue }` since numeric values will be automatically converted to string.

Here is an example of usage:

```
interface IDictionary<TValue> {
    [id: string]: TValue;
}

class Test {
    private dictionary: IDictionary<string>;

    constructor() {
       this.dictionary = {}
       this.dictionary[9] = "numeric-index";
       this.dictionary["10"] = "string-index"

       console.log(this.dictionary["9"], this.dictionary[10]);
    }
}
// result => "numeric-index string-index"
```

As you can see string and numeric indices are interchangeable.

Comment: Yeah I did that as well. I was amazed that TSLint didn't complain about me providing a number for a key. And it's working.

Answer (score 49):

In javascript the keys of object can only be strings (and in `es6` symbols as well).
If you pass a number it gets converted into a string:

```
let o = {};
o[3] = "three";
console.log(Object.keys(o)); // ["3"]
```

As you can see, you always get `{ [key: string]: TValue; }`.

Typescript lets you define a map like so with `number`s as keys:

```
type Dict = { [key: number]: string };
```

And the compiler will check that when assigning values you always pass a number as a key, but in runtime the keys in the object will be strings.

So you can either have `{ [key: number]: string }` or `{ [key: string]: string }` but not a union of `string | number` because of the following:

```
let d = {} as IDictionary<string>;
d[3] = "1st three";
d["3"] = "2nd three";
```

You might expect `d` to have two different entries here, but in fact there's just one.

What you can do, is use a `Map`:

```
let m = new Map<number|string, string>();
m.set(3, "1st three");
m.set("3", "2nd three");
```

Here you will have two different entries.

Comment: I had no idea this was true.  Sure enough `Object.keys({ 1: "a", 2: "b", 3: "c" }).map(key => typeof key)` returns `["string", "string", "string"]`.  Neat!

Answer (score 1):

Even though object keys are always strings under the hood, and typing indexers as strings covers numbers, sometimes you want a function to be aware of the keys of objects being passed into it.  Consider this mapping function which works like `Array.map` but with objects:

```
function map<T>(obj: Object, callback: (key: string, value: any) => T): T[] {
    // ...
}
```

`key` is restricted to being a `string`, and value is entirely untyped.  Probably fine 9 out of 10 times, but we can do better.  Let's say we wanted to do something silly like this:

```
const obj: {[key: number]: string} = { 1: "hello", 2: "world", 3: "foo", 4: "bar" };
map(obj, (key, value) => `${key / 2} ${value}`);
// error: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number' or an enum type.
```

We can't perform any arithmetic operations on key without first casting it to a number (remember: `"3" / 2` is valid in JS and resolves to a `number`).  We can get around this with a little bit of tricky typing on our map function:

```
function map<S, T>(obj: S, callback: (key: keyof S, value: S[keyof S]) => T): T[] {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(key => callback(key as any, (obj as any)[key]));
}
```

Here, we use the generic `S` to type our object, and look up key and value types directly from that.  If your object is typed using generic indexers and values, `keyof S` and `S[keyof S]` will resolve to constant types.  If you pass in an object with explicate properties, `keyof S` will be restricted to the property names and `S[keyof S]` will be restricted to the property value types.