# How to access a field of an object in Typescript using get method?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

In Typescript I have defined an interface:

```
interface IPriority {
    KEY1: number;
    KEY2: number;
    KEY3: number;
    DEFAULT: number;
}
```

I pass an object of type `IPriority` to a function, something like this:

```
    class Foo {
        async someFunction(priority: IPriority) {
        const someMap: Map<string, string> = new Map();
        //someMap has been properly initialized and has valid data
        const key = someMap.get("KEY1") ?? "KEY1";
        //const key = "KEY1";
        if(key) {
          const temp = priority[key];
          console.log(temp);
        }
      }
    }
```

Doing this, I get this error: `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'IPriority'. No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'IPriority'.`.

If I change `const temp = priority[key];` to this `const temp = priority.get(key)`, I get this error: `Property 'get' does not exist on type 'IPriority'.`

How can I access the values of `KEY1`, `KEY2`, ... using `get` method or with object index syntax (`priority[key]`)?

Here's a link to the [code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=7&ssc=1&pln=18&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUrAPZbAT2QG8AoZZAaQFEBNARgC5kQBXAWwCNoBuMy2gExNWnHn2o0AzMPZcovAL4kSCADZwAzhuQAxbNmJ9N%20EAmQbsbCDpamwOEAAoADllzACTDG7z4AlIbk5AjYIBpg5pYQALJwzkyxzgA84VggAOYANOZgaekAfMgAvMwQAO7IiY5%20vEHIAPT1FlaJyAAWmshcECDIrtjO0KqEoB7AcKrAAF4QACbIcCDzHdoAbhPA87NwYHB8waHhyADWEIQlzTFxAHTpEGCOAEQSdI8BAPzvyM%200r7VBjRCYQip3O3xej3%205GAMEcoICpDqB2ByEgbGcxT6Pg8%20AA2qCALpQoJAiyqCDXVTYdKONHOGr7ZBKchKBRAA)

Comment: What's the problem with `priority[key]`?

Comment: @enzo "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'IPriority'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'IPriority'."

Comment: @StupidMan [that error does not occur with your example code](https://tsplay.dev/mplRgm) so you should write `priority[key]` or change the question to include a true [mcve].

Comment: @StupidMan You've got "Element implicitly has an 'any' type ..." error because you may don't define key as `const` key.
See [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUrAPZbAT2QG8BYAKGUuQGkBRATQEYAuZEAVwFsAjaAbnJUaDAEysOPfoKp16AZnFdeUAWQC+5cgDc4UZAAcsuYAVYYjeQgF5islowAMAGlliRz2QrkO1q8gBsIMGQ4ZBsAIjtw1R09GDCDCxN8AG04AF0-MgRsEABnYIBrCEIEyIZGaM0yWOQYRgTDHEsU4vxM6qA)

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi This is my updated code: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUrAPZbAT2QG8AoZZAaQFEBNARgC5kQBXAWwCNoBuMy2gExNWnHn2o0AzMPZcovAL4kSCADZwAzhuQAxbNmJ9N+EAmQbsbCDpamwOEAAoADllzACTDG7z4AlIbk5AjYIBpg5pYQALJwzkyxzgA84VggAOYANMyy0AB8yAC8zBAA7siJjn68QcgA9HUWVonIABaayFwQIMiu2M7QqoSgHsBwqsAAXhAAJshwIHPt2gBu48BzM3BgcHzBoeHIANYQhMVNMXEAdOkQYI4ARBJ0D9V79XUhYREnZ8hPtBeNSCwBgjl+AVItX232QkDYziKvR8HnwAG1fgBdYHkJS4kgKIA Can you please check?

Comment: @StupidMan Sure. The problem is that your const `key` may get an undefined value. Put your cursor on your `key` and see that `number | undefined`

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi But on line 13, I am checking the truth value of `key` and only if its true (if its undefined its truth value will be false) the code inside if block will run. So why is it still showing the error? How can I fix this error?

Comment: @StupidMan Your const key must be a string not number or undefined. This is required for compiler.

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi I have changed `key` so now key is always of type string. But the error is still there: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=5&pln=11&pc=47#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUrAPZbAT2QG8AoZZAaQFEBNARgC5kQBXAWwCNoBuMy2gExNWnHn2o0AzMPZcovAL4kSCADZwAzhuQAxbNmJ9N+EAmQbsbCDpamwOEAAoADllzACTDG7z4AlIbk5AjYIBpg5pYQALJwzkyxzgA84VggAOYANOZgaekAfMgAvMwQAO7IiY5+vEHIAPT1FlaJyAAWmshcECDIrtjO0KqEoB7AcKrAAF4QACbIcCDzHdoAbhPA87NwYHB8waHhyADWEIQlzTFxAHTpEGCOAEQSdI8BAPzvyM+0r7VBjRCYQip3O3xej3+5GAMEcoICpDqB2ByEgbGcxT6Pg8+AA2qCALpQoJAiyqCDXVTYdKONHOGr7ZBKchKBRAA

Comment: Apparently compiler needs predefined value. You have two options:
1. use `any` keyword like that `(priority as any)[key]`
2. create dictionary see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870411/object-index-key-type-in-typescript)

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi Thanks a lot. I am going with the first option for now but looks like I have a lot to learn about Typescript.

Comment: @StupidMan OK. I'm going to answer instead of comment to better use of everybody

Comment: `someMap` will have only valid `IPriority` keys as values? If yes - `const someMap: Map<string, keyof IPriority> = new Map();` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUrAPZbAT2QG8AoZZAaQFEBNARgC5kQBXAWwCNoBuMy2gExNWnHn2o0AzMPZcovAL4kSCADZwAzhuQAxbNmJ9N+EAmQbsbCDpamwOEAAoADllzACTDG7z4AlIbk5AjYIBpg5pYQALJwzkyxzgA84VggAOYANMgA1hD42DBomDi+AHzIALzMEADuyImOfrxByAD0bRZWicgAFprIXBAgyK7YztCqhKAewHCqwABeEAAmyHAga-3aAG7zwGsrcGBwfMGh4bn5VZHdcQB06RBgjgBEEnSvAQD838jvtE+LSCHRCYQieUI1QB9FewPIwBgjkhAVIrXO4OQkDYzhurlKHnwAG1IQBdeFBMEWVQQe6qbDpRzY5zNM7IJTkJQKIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently compiler needs predefined value for index. You have two options:

1. use `any` keyword like that `(priority as any)[key]`
2. create dictionary see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870411/object-index-key-type-in-typescript)

Answer (score 2):

As [Alireza Ahmadi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11359076/alireza-ahmadi) said, It's better to use dictionary in typescript instead of your `interface` and `Map`. But if you would like to insist on your code and use the written code, you can find the value of the founded key with 2 functions which has been defined on `Object`: `Object.keys` and `Object.values`. You can change your `someFunctions` method to something like this:

```
interface IPriority {
  KEY1: string;
  KEY2: string;
  KEY3: string;
} 

class Foo {
   async someFunction(priority: IPriority) {
      const someMap: Map<string, string> = new Map();
      someMap.set("1", "KEY1");
      someMap.set("2", "KEY2");
      someMap.set("3", "KEY3");
      const key1 = someMap.get("1");
      if (key1) {
         let value: string = "";
         Object.keys(priority).map((propertyKey, propertyIndexKey) => {
           if (propertyKey == key1) {
              Object.values(priority).map((propertyValue, propertyIndexValue) => {
                 if (propertyIndexKey == propertyIndexValue) {
                    value = propertyValue;
                 }
           })
        }
        return value;
        })
        console.log(value);
     }
  }
}

const foo: Foo = new Foo();
const priority: IPriority = {
  KEY1: "1",
  KEY2: "2",
  KEY3: "3",
}
foo.someFunction(priority)// "1"
```