# Get type of object keys typescript

Tags: typescript

Got object like this and my question is how to use label as a index and typescript not complains

```
const en = {
    "account.options.global.description": "Set your default language and theme",
    "account.options.global.title": "Global preferences",
    "account.options.login.description": "Update your password and secure your account",
    "account.options.login.section.button.alternatetitle": "Set password",
    "account.options.login.section.button.title": "Update password",
    "account.options.login.section.login": "Login",
}

export interface CountriesI {
  value: Countries;
  label: string --> what should be correct;
}

const countries: CountriesI[] = [
  {value: Countries.ARG, label: 'common.countries.options.argentina'},
  {value: Countries.BOL, label: 'common.countries.options.bolivia'},
  {value: Countries.BRA, label: 'common.countries.options.brasil'},
  {value: Countries.COL, label: 'common.countries.options.colombia'},
  {value: Countries.CHL, label: 'common.countries.options.chile'},
  {value: Countries.ECU, label: 'common.countries.options.ecuador'},
  {value: Countries.GUY, label: 'common.countries.options.guyana'},
  {value: Countries.MEX, label: 'common.countries.options.mexico'},]

//complains index is not a type

countries.map((element) => {
return {...element,  en[element.label]}
})
```

Comment: Keys in JavaScript are always `string` values - or `number` if you include `Array` (or `Symbol` in ES6+). Using anything else as a key will implicitly call `toString` IIRC.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Object index key type in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870411/object-index-key-type-in-typescript)

Comment: Why is there an `I` at the end of `CountriesI`? If you're using it to denote an interface then you should not be doing that. Interfaces in TypeScript are not like interfaces in .NET or COM and you should not be using Systems Hungarian notation.

Comment: the answer is type data_key = keyof typeof en; Countries{..., label: data_key} then typescript stop complaining