# Angular pipe to reduce objects based on the array of object keys

Tags: typescript, angular-pipe

I want to create pipe in Angular to reduce my object and return only certain key:value pairs based on the array of strings that represent the object.keys that I am sure will be present within the object.
I have tried to implement my solution with the help of this thread [Object index key type in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41870411/object-index-key-type-in-typescript) but I manage to get my keys but their values are always undefined.

html file:

```
  <ng-container *ngFor="let keyValue of asset | filterProperties: arrayOfObjectKeys ; let i = index">  
    <div class="details-col">
      <span class="key">
       {{ keyValue.value}} :
      </span>

      <span class="value">
        {{ keyValue.key }}
      </span>

    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

ts file:

```
 arrayOfObjectKeys = ['name', 'quantity', 'code']
```

pipe:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'

@Pipe({
  name: 'filterProperties',
  standalone: true,
})

export class FilterPropertiesPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(object: Record<string, any>, keys: string[]) {

    const omit = <T extends {}, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, ...keys: K[]) => {

      Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([key]) => !keys.includes(key as K))) as Omit<T, K>
    }

    console.log('OBJECT', omit(object)) 
    return omit(object)
  }
}
```

just one precision: MyObject can be multiple types and even complex deep objects but I am sure that arrayOfObjectKeys will always have values that are equal to objectKeys of the passed object.

Thank you!

Comment: Aren't you missing an explicit return in `omit` ?

Comment: no even if I add this it is not working